# Retrieve socket handle from SqlConnection object

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, ado.net

I would get socket handle that connecting to remote sqlserver, I only have `SqlConnection` object, How could I do that?

In `Windows2008`, I can use internal function `GetBestEffortCleanupTarget` for walk around, but it doesn't work on `Windows2012`.

Comment: What makes you think there's a socket handle? What if the connection isn't using TCP/IP?

Comment: Assume I'm using TCP to connect to remote sqlserver

Comment: I can't imagine that there's a socket handle you can get at. That's a private implementation detail of the connection. What were you trying to accomplish? Even if you could access it, I doubt you could _use_ it for anything.

Comment: Actually, I want to log this connection information, e.g the source port I'm connection from. I have to get them from SqlConnection, right?

Comment: You should probably stop reinventing the wheel. Chances are that SQL Server already knows how to log this information. Did you look in the SQL Server logs? I would also suggest that this information is none of your business. It's an internal implementation detail. What if some day, SQL Server decides to use multiple connections? What if it decides to rotate between connections, so that one connection uses port A, and the next uses port B?